# How to build the game for android platform as described below?

Tags: android, graphics

Game description:

Display consist of N X N dots(.) that is N rows consists of N dots seperated by equal space.

I want to make a two players game.when a player touch between two points a line(either horizontal or vertical) connect the points.PlayerA and PlayerB represented by different colors. player who complete the box will get 1 point.
At the end player having high score will be declared as winner.I am not getting from where to begin.I google but i get confuse with terms Bitmap,Canvas.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this:  http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

Comment: Start with a game development engine, I suggest LibGDX http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com. it's free, open source and still active and best of all it's multi-platform (Android, Desktop and IOS)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use some library/framework for game development. I recommend libgdx [1]. It's open source, quite mature, has an active community and very good Documentation. This will also allow you to preview your work in your desktop environment instead of having to deploy to an android device after every change.

You might also want to check out the tutorial at [2] to get a feel for the basic concepts.

[1] http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

[2] https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game